# How to set focus to an antd Input.Password component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to set focus an `input.password` field. Is it possible?

I didnt see any information on antd docs. I wonder if its possible

`Input(Input.TextArea)` has a `Input(textAreaRef)` property through ref. but in `Input.Password`, I can't find anything about this. Is there a way to accomplish my question?

Comment: Hi there, without code showing what you've tried, not really possible to give any specific advice.

Comment: sorry, wait a monment, i'll post a codesandbox  link.

Comment: [code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bell-exues)

Answer (score 6):

Password inputs are no different than other text inputs.  First you must create a reference to the input, then you can call its `focus()` method at any point to focus the input.  The code below focuses the input when the component mounts:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Icon, Input } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  passwordInput = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.passwordInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input
          prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          ref={input => {
            this.passwordInput = input;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LoginForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Try it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/password-focus-h4epm)

Comment: thanks for your reply, It's no problem when use Input's type attr. but i use <Input.Password /> instead <Input type='password' />. form.Input type of password and added in 3.12.0.

Comment: I post a example to codesandbox, you can find [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bell-exues)

Comment: Is there any major difference between `<Input.Password />` and `<Input type='password' />` ?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you point with ref to Component instead of DOM-element, so, try this:

**In case of Input component from antd library:**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Input, Form } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const MyComponent = () => {
  // Same as React.createRef()
  const passwordInput = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (passwordInput.current) {
      // or, if Input component in your ref, then use input property like:
      // passwordInput.current.input.focus();
      passwordInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, [passwordInput]);

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item name="login">
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="password">
        <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" ref={passwordInput} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**In case of DOM Element**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const MyComponent2 = () => {
  const passwordInput = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (passwordInput.current) {
      passwordInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, [passwordInput]);

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ref={passwordInput} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyComponent2;
```

This is example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-water-khhwb?file=/src/index.js)

P.S. useEffect hook works almost same as componentDidMount in Class component

Comment: hi,
I tried the above solution for antd TextArea but it isn’t working. Any further suggestions for TextArea??

Answer (score 3):

You can also use refs for Input.password.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.password = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.password.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="password" ref={this.password}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.